# Serving media files in Chunks

Tags: python, django

I have huge video files (size: 200mb average) stored in my media folder.
I fetch those files using `os.listdir` and then store them in dictionary, with respect to storing filename, date (fetch from file) and time (fetched from file) against each file in the dir `'../media/videos/'`. Refer to code below:

```
file_names = [os.path.join('../media/videos/',fn) for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.startswith(example_20_Apr_20)]
    file_names_final=[]
    for item in file_names:
            tmp=item.split("-")
            file_names_final.append({'file_name':item,'date':"-".join(tmp[-6:-3]),'time':"-".join(tmp[-3:-1])})
    print(file_names_final) #for debugging
```

Then i place those files in the template. Refer to code section below:

```
{% for i in files %}
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="alert-card clickable-feed-wrapper">
                            <div class="old-feeds-video-wrapper">
                                <video class="video-container" preload="auto">
                                    <source src="{{ i.file_name }}#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert-details">
                                <span class="h">Location : <span class="d feed-location-info">{{location}}</span></span><br/>
                                <span class="h"><span class="d feed-pilot-info"></span></span>
                                <span class="h">Date : <span class="d feed-time-info">{{i.date}}</span></span><br/>
                                <span class="h">Time (24h): <span class="d feed-time-info">{{i.time}}</span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

**FYI,** im passing `file_names_final` in `context` as `files`

The problem that I'm running into is, when I try to stream the files from external network, I just can't load the huge files that may size **around 200mb**, however i'm able to stream the files that are roughly within the **10mb to 50mb** ballpark.

This may primarily be due to the internet connectivity, and it is bound to happen, but this issue kept me wondering, does the django development server have an issue with large files being streamed? Just a wild thought!

***But what i would like to achieve is, to break this video files in suitable chunks, and then server them in the html5 video player, through django/python***

Comment: You are serving the files using the development server and don't have apache/nginx serving them for you?

Comment: My project is currently running on development server, so yes, serving the files using dev server, and in settings.py file, added the machine ip as allowed hosts, which allows me to access the project outside my local network.